# Spring boot profile and environment in the logfile name

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

How can I write the Spring Profile and the Spring Environment in the logfile name of a log file with Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="env">????</Property>
        <Property name="profile">????</Property>
        <Property name="date">%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogToFile" filePattern="./logs/filename_${env}_${profile}_${date}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Log4j 2.13.1 and include log4j-spring-cloud-config-client-2.13.1.jar as a dependency. This will provide you access to the Spring Lookup, which will give you access to any property defined in your application.yml or bootstrap.yml. You can then add

```
spring:
  profile: lab
  env: dev
```

to your Spring configurations and then set your log4j2.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="profile">${spring:spring.profile:-default}</Property>
        <Property name="env">${spring:spring.env:-dev}</Property>
        <Property name="date">%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogToFile" filePattern="./logs/filename_${env}_${profile}_${date}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

With this Log4j will then retrieve the values from the Spring environment once it is initialized. Note that a Spring Boot application will initialize logging at least 3 times, with the first occurring before Spring has an environment. You can use a different logging configuration for that case by configuring its location in log4j2.component.properties and then specifying a different logging configuration file in bootstrap.yml. Log4j 2 provides a [sample application](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/master/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-samples/log4j-spring-cloud-config-sample-application) that utilizes this as well as accessing its configuration file in a Spring Cloud Config Server.

Note that if you store your log4j2.xml file in Spring Cloud Configuration you can use a different Log4j configuration for each environment and eliminate the need for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this blog is helpful

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/profile-logback-logging-config.html

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.main.logStartupInfo=false
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

use `${sys:spring.profiles.active}`, as any arguments given with -D count as SystemProperties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="profile">${sys:spring.profiles.active}</Property>
        <Property name="date">%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogToFile" filePattern="./logs/filename_${profile}_${date}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %c{1} - %message%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```